# How to read certain attributes of only one aside section itself?

Tags: jquery

On click of a button , the response of a div is

```
var htmlString = $("div#"+id_attr_val+".Topping-details").eq(0).html(); 
console.log('response is'+htmlString);
```

Response of this is

```
<section id="topping_tsection_59">
   <i id="topping-close"></i>
   <aside>
      <h6 class="tdHeading">Regular, 50 Ml0</h6>
      <img src="images/arrow-topping.png">
      <section class="secclass"><a href="#">Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML</a></section>
      <section class="secclass"><a href="#">Honey with Carmel  10 ML</a></section>
   </aside>
   <aside>
      <h6 class="tdHeading">Regular, 50 Ml1</h6>
      <img src="images/arrow-topping.png">
      <section class="secclass"><a href="#">Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML</a></section>
      <section class="secclass"><a href="#">Honey with Carmel  10 ML</a></section>
   </aside>
</section>
```

How can i read text  of a href tag of only first aside section itself ??

That is i need the output as

```
Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML

Honey with Carmel  10 ML
```

I tried this way

```
$("#topping-close aside a ").each(function(){
           var category=$(this).text();
           console.log('categories'+category);
         return false;
       });
```

But nothing is being printed , could anybody please help .

Comment: just check it http://jsfiddle.net/kka284556/LXC88/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USe `first-child`

```
$("#topping_tsection_59 aside a:first-child")
```

**Edit**

```
$("#topping_tsection_59 aside a:first").each(function(){
  alert($(this).text())
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z46fs/4/)

Comment: Getting all the aside section contents .

Comment: I needed only one pair of Honey with Chocolate Sauce 10 MfL
Honey with Carmel 10 ML , but its giving me multiple times .

Answer (score 0):

try this.... you are using wrong selector

```
 $("#topping_tsection_59 aside:first a ").each(function(){
               var category=$(this).text();
               console.log('categories'+category);

           });
```

You can change your selector..it will work

Answer (score 0):

First off, the selector you're using is looking for `aside a` elements that are *children* of an element with the ID of `topping-close`. In the markup you've provided, there are no children of that element, which is the `i` (which has no children). You probably want a selector like this (because your `aside`s *are* children of a `section`):

```
$("section aside")
```

However, regarding finding the "first" `aside`, jQuery has a `first()` function. The below will, assuming you fix the above, find the the first `aside` that is a child of an element with the id of `topping-close` (then find the `a` element inside that `aside`).

```
$("#topping-close aside").first().find("a")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get with Jquery

```
var text="";
$('#topping_tsection_59 aside').filter(':first').find('a').each(function(){
text +=$(this).text()+"<br />";
});
```

Please run the given code it can help you I have not tested it but let me know if it's not work for you. I'll update it again.